# Youtube video and text side by side in Markdown

Tags: html, html-table, markdown

I would like to have some text like on the right...

```
##Features

* Feature 1
* Feature 2
* Feature 3
```

and a Youtube video on the left. How to do it properly?

[image]

---

I tried things [like this](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#tables), unsucessfully:

```
| | |
|-|-|
|<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vNp85kiMXK0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>|
##Features

* Feature 1
* Feature 2
* Feature 3
|
```

---

### Edit

I also tried this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td width="50%">
<iframe width="300" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vNp85kiMXK0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</td>
<td width="50%">
##Features
* Feature 1
* Feature 2
* Feature 3
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

but then **impossible to use Markdown in the table anymore**: the Markdown is not parsed and is rendered by Parsedown like normal text...

Answer (score 0):

Markdown is [deliberately simple](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html):

> Markdown is not a replacement for HTML, or even close to it. Its syntax is very small, corresponding only to a very small subset of HTML tags. The idea is *not* to create a syntax that makes it easier to insert HTML tags. In my opinion, HTML tags are already easy to insert. The idea for Markdown is to make it easy to read, write, and edit prose. HTML is a *publishing* format; Markdown is a *writing* format. Thus, Markdown’s formatting syntax only addresses issues that can be conveyed in plain text.

It doesn't include support for lots of things, including tables¹ and columns. For things like this, simply use HTML:

> For any markup that is not covered by Markdown’s syntax, you simply use HTML itself. There’s no need to preface it or delimit it to indicate that you’re switching from Markdown to HTML; you just use the tags.

¹Some Markdown implementations add support for things that aren't in the original spec, with tables being a common one. This support isn't well standardized, and you'll have to specify the implementation that you're using if you want an implementation-specific solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using http://parsedown.org/, that uses [Markdown Extra extension](https://github.com/erusev/parsedown-extra). Do you think there is a way with this version of Markdown?

Comment: I tried with a html `<table>` but then its Markdown content is not parsed and is rendered like normal text (see edit in my question). Any idea @Chris ?

Comment: @Basj, that's the way Markdown works. Within HTML, Markdown is not processed. I haven't used Parsedown or Markdown Extra, but it [looks like you should be able to get Markdown inside your HTML by adding a `markdown="1"` attribute to the containing HTML](https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/#markdown-attr).