# SimpleMDE - Markdown embeding videos from Youtube

Tags: php, iframe, youtube, r-markdown, parsedown

I 'm using [SmpleMDE](https://simplemde.com/) as my WYSIWYG editor and the [Parsedown](http://parsedown.org) library for parsing the markdown and converting it into HTML.

`<?php echo $this->parsedown->text($post->content); ?>`

Everything works fine, the only problem is that I want to show up
 youtube videos within the content by adding the embeded `<iframe>`.

According to this answer [Youtube video and text side by side in Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30259661/youtube-video-and-text-side-by-side-in-markdown) I can simply add the youtube `<iframe>` straight to my content, however the output shows the html code escaped

```
<p>&lt;iframe width=&quot;560&quot; height=&quot;315&quot; src=&quot;<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7GqClqvlObY">https://www.youtube.com/embed/7GqClqvlObY</a>&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;</p>
```

The content in the database is stored like this

```
Lorem ipsum .....

&lt;iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7GqClqvlObY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;


Lorem ipsum .....
```

How can I fix this so that the embeded code from youtube would show up properly?

Comment: Somewhere along the chain you have a textfilter doing some escaping of the tags. What is the value of `$post->content`? If that text looks okay, it's parsedown that makes the conversion, if not, then it's SimpleMDE.

Comment: Did an update on post, Iguess there's an escaping on tags before saving in db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the problem is that the strings are stored escaped in the database, try this:

```
<?php echo $this->parsedown->text(htmlspecialchars_decode($post->content); ?>
```

Also, take a look at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php), you might have to add a flag depending on how your strings are encoded/escaped.

Comment: I was trying this the other way around, like this `htmlspecialchars_decode($this->parsedown->text($post->content))` but didn't work. This one works fine! Thanks :-)